# Trying to call recursive method with parameters, but parameters not holding

Tags: java, swing, recursion, jpanel

I am trying to create a Mondrian Generator in which a rectangle is recursively subdivided until its size meets a certain threshold. Within this program, I am trying to call a recursive method with defined values

```
public class Mondrian extends JPanel {
    private static final int CUTOFF = 40;
    private Random rng = new Random();
    static private Image mondrian;

    public Mondrian(int w, int h) {
        mondrian = new BufferedImage(w, h, TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) mondrian.getGraphics();
        subdivide(0, 0, 800, 1000, g2);
    }
```

which is subsequently calling on this method

```
private void subdivide(int tx, int ty, int w, int h, Graphics2D g2) {
    g2.setColor(Color.white);
    g2.fillRect(0,0, mondrian.getHeight(null), mondrian.getWidth(null));
    while (w > CUTOFF || h > CUTOFF) {
        System.out.println(w);
        Random randomSize = new Random();
        double size = randomSize.nextDouble();
        if (size < 0.6){
                int rndColour = rng.nextInt(COLORS.length);
                Color colour = COLORS[rndColour];
                g2.setColor(colour);
                subdivide(tx, ty, (w * (int) size), (h * (int) size), g2);
                g2.fillRect(tx, ty, tx-w, ty-h);
                g2.setColor(colour);
                subdivide(tx, ty, (w * (int) (1 - size)), (h * (int) (1 - size)), g2);
                g2.fillRect(tx, ty, tx-w, ty-h);
            g2.drawLine((w * (int) size), (h * (int) size), (w * (int) (1 - size)), (h * (int) (1 - size)));
        }
    }
}
```

However, this function runs forever, as even though the values of w and h are set in the original method call, they are set to zero for some reason.

This is the main method, however I don't think there is anything wrong with it, I think its mostly to do with the class

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Mondrian mondrian = new Mondrian(800, 1000);
    frame.add(mondrian);
    frame.setSize(800, 1000);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

For what I have tried, I have tried to set the values of w and h within the recursive function itself, but it never shrinks. I have also tried setting explicit vlaues of w and h within the initial call, but the values are still set to 0. I don't know where else to go with this as something has to fundamentally be wrong with my code.

Comment: I might be missing something: `while (w > CUTOFF || h > CUTOFF)` where are w and h modified so this loop will end?